# How do I add my phaser.js game to my pre-made web page?

Tags: javascript, html5, phaser

First off, it's my first time doing a little bit of game development, and I have no idea of the normal flow of making a game, let alone a browser game.

My game uses the phaser framework of HTML and JavaScript. It is a simple game based on the 2D space impact game. I was able to run the game on an empty HTML site with only head, title, and body tags.

This is the code to plug in my game to the blank HTML site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I tried to add it to my pre-made website, it won't show.
Am I missing anything? Do I need to put it in an iFrame, although I know phaser builds on a canvas.

Comment: Did you verify that you game JS file is actually found and loaded (and no errors/exceptions occurred) for example with the inbuilt network tools modern browsers have?

Comment: hmmm does running it on my another html page rule out errors? ill have a look and tell you. thanks

Comment: When it works in a very simple HTML document but not in a very complex one, there must be *something* in your complex document which prevents it from working. It is impossible for us to guess it. So what you need to do is continually remove more and more stuff from your actual website until you find the thing which prevents it from working. Then we can help you to find out *why* this thing prevents it from working.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are creating your game within game.js, but don't forget to specify the `parent` option with an ID or element, so that Phaser knows where to put your game. I think if you don't specify that, it will just throw it at the end of your body tag, which probably isn't ideal. More notes on `parent` here: http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.Game.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I solved my own problem. it seems that a simpler way to put it would have to place the game on another html page and then embed it with an `iFrame` tag! like

```
<iframe src="game.html" height="550" width="800">game not available</iframe>
```

And the text "game not available" is a displayed text when the iFrame fails no embed the content from the source as a DEFAULT.

The reason for this problem might have been the conflicting javascript libraries of the Twitter bootstrap im using and the js library of the phaser framework.